# "I don’t have as much of an appetite", could someone verify my explanation?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I've read these sentences:
In summer, when the weather is warmer, I don’t have as much of an appetite, so I’ll eat something lighter.

The part that confuses me is 'I don't have as much of an appetite'(as in winter).

1. I don't have as much of an appetite = I don't have as much appetite. Are they the same?
2. The sentence is actually some kind of combination between 'as much...as'(the second 'as' is left out) and 'not much of an'(which means 'my appetite is of poor quality/not at a high level'). Is my explanation correct? Or there are other reasons for using 'as much of an appetite' instead of 'as much appetite'?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: “… as much of an… ” is pretty-much exactly the same as “… as much… 

Don’t you think you might get more suitable help somewhere like English Language Learners?

Comment: No, _I don't have much appetite_ does **not** mean the same thing as _I don't have as much appetite_. The second one is a comparative -- _not as much X_ means less X than previous X -- whereas the first one is a straightforward negative polarity item. _Not much_ means "little" because _much_ and _many_ in the scope of a negative trigger are idioms. It's the same structure as "He's not the sharpest pencil in the box", which means he's the dullest.